# Converted date does not changes in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I declare my date element in this format in view.

```
<li>{{dt.Joindate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</li>      //output: Wed Feb 05 2014 15:39:46 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) comes like this
```

My data comes as a string,i converted the string date in javascript but the date field does not shows like MM-dd-yyyy

Javascript code:

```
angular.forEach(response.Data,function(item){
               item.Joindate=Date(item.Joindate);
               $scope.retrieveddata.push(item);;
               });
```

Comment: What is the value of the elements of `$scope.retrieveddata`

Comment: $scope.retriveddata is an array...

Comment: $scope.Postcall = function()
        {
              $http.post('Home/postdatainangular', { name: 'Sriram',dept: 'Civil',Joindate: today }).success(function(response)
               {
                   if(response.Result == "OK")
                   {
                   angular.forEach(response.Data,function(item){
                   item.Joindate=Date(item.Joindate);
                   $scope.retrieveddata.push(item);;
                   });
                   }
               });
        }